# Babel won't compile a file when there's a nested package.json file

Tags: node.js, reactjs, webpack, babeljs

I'm using WebPack, Babel and React. I have a folder structure like the below

```
node_modules/
.babelrc
package.json
    SomeThirdPartyFolder/
        node_modules/
        package.json  
        src/
           FileA.js
```

I wanted to use FileA which has jsx content, however it acted as though Babel wasn't there, i.e. it produced a compile error on the below

```
  return (
      <div className etc
```

If I remove the package.json in SomeThirdPartyFolder then it does compile

Clearly this isn't a real situation but I'd like to understand what's happening here

Comment: Have you read through https://babeljs.io/docs/en/config-files ?

Comment: Thanks for the link. It seems like I want to convert the file relative .babelrc file into a project wide babel.config.js. I've added it above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Based off loganfsmyth's comments)

I've converted the .babelrc file into a babel.config.js file and it now seems to work. The .babelrc file was

```
{
    "presets": [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ],
    "plugins": [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            {
                "loose": true
            }
        ]
    ]
}
```

And the replacement file is

```
module.exports = function (api)
{
    api.cache(true);

    const presets = [
        "@babel/preset-env",
        "@babel/preset-react"
    ];
    const plugins = [
        [
            "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties",
            {
                "loose": true
            }
        ]
    ];

    return {
        presets,
        plugins
    };
}
```